# Rails migration change time to datetime preserving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I need to change my column 'start_time' from time to datetime
(Am I correct in that datetime and timestamp are the same thing? NOTE: I'm on postgres)

```
class ChangeStartTimeToBeDatetimeInAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    change_column :assignments, :start_time, :datetime
  end
  def down
    change_column :assignments, :start_time, :time
  end
end
```

The data in the column is important so it can't be deleted...

Note: here is a snippet of the json output displaying only the "start_time" portion (if it matters)

```
"start_time":"2000-01-01T12:00:00"
```

This error occurs when I migrate:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "start_time" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING start_time::timestamp without time zone".
```

Running this migration...

```
class ChangeStartTimeToBeDatetimeInAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    change_column :assignments, :start_time, :datetime, 'USING start_time::timestamp without time zone'
  end
  def down
    change_column :assignments, :start_time, :time
  end
end
```

Gives this error...

```
== 20210916230930 ChangeStartTimeToBeDatetimeInAssignments: migrating =========
-- change_column(:assignments, :start_time, :datetime, "USING start_time::timestamp without time zone")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

What am I doing wrong?

How do I migrate "time" to "datetime"?

How do I modify my migration and add "USING start_time::timestamp without time zone" as suggested?

(Am I correct in that datetime and timestamp are the same thing?)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: ActiveRecords `:datetime`  type corresponds to the `timestamp` type on Postgres. Its driver dependent so on MySQL `DATETIME` is for example used instead. You should be able to use something like `change_column :assignments, :start_time, :datetime, "USING start_time::timestamp without time zone"`.

Comment: @max the exact incantation is what I'm looking for. `change_column :assignments, :start_time, :datetime, "USING start_time::timestamp without time zone"`  gives an error. updated my question to show such what I got when I ran the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of readability just make everything step by step. This also will help with defining a proper down method to make sure rollbacks won't error out.

```rb
class ChangeStartTimeToBeDatetimeInAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    # add a temporary column
    add_column :assignments, :start_time_datetime, :datetime
    
    # add the the current start_time as datetime to the temporary column for each entry
    Assignment.all.each do |assignment|
      assignment.update(start_time_datetime: assignment.start_time.to_datetime)
    end

    # drop the old time column
    remove_column :assignments, :start_time
    
    # rename the temporary column to start_time   
    rename_column :assignments, :start_time_datetime, :start_time
  end

  def down
    add_column :assignments, :start_time_time, :time
    
    Assignment.all.each do |assignment|
      assignment.update(start_time_time: assignment.start_time.to_time
    end

    remove_column :assignments, :start_time
    rename_column :assignments, :start_time_time, :start_time
  end
end
```

To ensure that the update loop does not error out because of data inconsistency and leaving you with half messed up data you can wrap the update part into a https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html